# ttk Checkbutton select and readonly?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, ttk

I am using Python 2.7, is there a way to preselect/deselect a Checkbutton in ttk?? As well as making it read-only?

I am trying to display the selected option from a file.

Comment: by preselected, i mean selecting the checkbutton by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, the correct syntax would be something like

```
    self.mon = ttk.Checkbutton(self.dow, text = 'MON')
    self.mon.state(['selected'])
    self.mon.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

I've seen it on a couple of sites, but their syntax are off, this is the correct way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an option to have a readonly `Checkbutton` without disabling it.

A not-so-ugly hack to achieve this is to tie the checkbox to a variable that controlled by your application. A well placed `command` parameter can make sure the value does not change on user input:

```
var = IntVar(root)
var.set(0)
cb = Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=lambda: var.set(1-var.get()))
```